# search if string from a pds is present in another pds

Tags: zos, jcl

I have a pds (say A) having jobnames (superset).
I have another pds (say B) having lesser number of jobnames (subset).

best way to find a A-B into another file C using JCL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [SYNCORT JOINKEYS](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r12.icea100%2Fjoinkeys.htm),
this [example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r12.icea100%2Fice1ca50124.htm) is pretty much
what you need. The JCL below is a specific example. `AF1` is the Superset file (A) containing all job names, `AF2` is the Subset
file (B). `SORTOUT` will contain the difference (A-B).

```
//MYJOB   JOB Whatever your job card needs
//AMINUSB    EXEC  PGM=SYNCSORT,PARM='INCORE=OFF'
//AF1  DD *                 Superset file 'A'
J000001
J000002
J000003
J000004
J000005
J000006
J000007
J000008
J000009
J000010
J000011
J000012
/*
//BF2  DD *                  Subset file 'B'
J000001
J000003
J000004
J000008
J000010
J000011
/*
//SORTOUT    DD SYSOUT=*    'A' - 'B'
//*
//SORTMSG   DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSOUT    DD SYSOUT=*
//CEEDUMP   DD SYSOUT=*
//STATOUT   DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN     DD *
  JOINKEYS FILE=F1,FIELDS=(1,7,A)
  JOINKEYS FILE=F2,FIELDS=(1,7,A)
  JOIN UNPAIRED,F1,ONLY
  REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,7)
  OPTION COPY
  END
/*
```

If you run this, `SORTOUT` will contain the following data:

```
J000002 
J000005 
J000006 
J000007 
J000009 
J000012
```

Note: You will have to refomat the `JOB` card to whatever your installation requires. The rest should work pretty much
as illustrated.